# Set size to select element in a form with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is only a question without any type of code attached.

In jQuery I can set a value to attribute with `$("something").attr("attr",value)`. Can i set the size of a select element in a HTML form based for example on the number characters in a text input? Say for example I want a size of 1 if the number of characters is <2 and a size of 5 if <2.

Is there a method in jQuery that allow me to do that?

Comment: Not a specific method, but just check the input text, and do some logic.

Comment: Yes you can. You want it to change as the user is typing or based on the value of another field?

Comment: @arcyqwerty while the user is typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an input, this code will set the size of the input to 1 if there are  2 or fewer characters and 5 otherwise

```
$('input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length > 2 ? 5 : 1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gy2Le8z3/

If you want it to be based on the length of input in another field, change `this` in `$(this).val().length` to reference that other field.

Comment: @arcqwerty so if i have a select element that i want dynamically to change the size i have to change the first this with the id of the select element right?

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/kkj5c267/

```
<input id="width" type="text" placeholder="width"/>
<input id="height" type="text" placeholder="height"/>
<div></div>
```

JS

```
$('#width').on('keyup', function(){
    $('div').width($(this).val());
})

$('#height').on('keyup', function(){
    $('div').height($(this).val());
})
```